# Django url path migration (1.11->3.1) warning for route symbols

Tags: django-urls, django-3

I'ved got this warning in Django 3.1.5 when doing the migration from 1.11

```
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern 'employee/attendanceactivity/attendance/(?P<attendance_id>\d+)/' [name='employee-attendanceactivity-detail'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().
```

here is the statement from url.py

```
path('employee/attendanceactivity/attendance/(?P<attendance_id>\d+)/', 
    views.employee_attendanceactivity_detail, name = 'employee-attendanceactivity-detail'),
```

How should I fix this warning ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Django 2.0 onwards, `re_path` should be used for matching regular expressions in URL patterns.

Modify your path as follows:

```py
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    re_path(r'^employee/attendanceactivity/attendance/(?P<attendance_id>\d+)/$', views.employee_attendanceactivity_detail, name = 'employee-attendanceactivity-detail'), 
    # ...
]
```

ref. Django URL dispatcher [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions).

Comment: you didnt had ^ ? like this re_path(r'^.... what is the difference omitting ^ ? @Awin

Comment: `^` means start of string and `$` is the end of string. Without them it will match the `re_path` even in between strings. Updated the answer to include both ^ and &

Comment: what if I have something like this, do I put $ at the end also -->    re_path(r'^order/list/view_order/(?P<order_id>\d+)', orderadmin_views.orderadmin_view_order, name='orderadmin_view_order'),

Comment: Yes, adding $ at the end results in a more specific regex. In your case, without a $, it will also match `order/list/view_order/123/some-string`.

Answer (score 0):

Stack won't let me comment, unfortunately, but the answer to your follow-on question is that the ^ at the start of the pattern is a [regex "start-of-line" anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). While your path will likely work without it, it's generally a good idea to include ^ at the start and $ at the end of your re_paths.